Application fails to receive packet, IP tables forwarded
I'm using iptables on debian. I have 2 servers, 1 for forwarding traffic and 1 hosting my application and accepting the traffic. I have setup the following rules on the first server -
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2476 packets, 102K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    6   328 DNAT       6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            15.235.163.198       tcp dpt:6900 to:10.8.0.18:6900
    0     0 DNAT       6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            15.235.163.198       tcp dpt:6900 to:10.8.0.18:6900
    0     0 DNAT       6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            15.235.163.198       tcp dpt:6900 to:10.8.0.18:6900

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2474 packets, 101K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 12574 packets, 755K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 12612 packets, 757K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      ens3    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      ens3    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      ens3    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0

Forwarded routes -
debian@2:~$ sudo iptables -L FORWARD -v -n
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 71 packets, 3708 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   208 ACCEPT     6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.8.0.18            tcp dpt:6900 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

I receive the packets on the second server -
debian@debian:~/build/bin/Debug$ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 port 6900
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
12:11:20.080001 IP 49.47.2.38.42978 > 10.8.0.18.6900: Flags [S], seq 3431906189, win 64240, options [mss 1399,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:11:21.096123 IP 49.47.2.38.42978 > 10.8.0.18.6900: Flags [S], seq 3431906189, win 64240, options [mss 1399,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:11:23.109073 IP 49.47.2.38.42978 > 10.8.0.18.6900: Flags [S], seq 3431906189, win 64240, options [mss 1399,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:11:27.110487 IP 49.47.2.38.42978 > 10.8.0.18.6900: Flags [S], seq 3431906189, win 64240, options [mss 1399,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

but my application fails to receive them. It doesn't show that it has received anything nor does it show any logs of the packets received on the second server. How is it that the server receives the traffic but the application fails to receive it? The application is bound on the correct IP address on port 6900. It worked the last time I had configured the same system. Can someone help me out here? what could be the issue?
